# How to determine if expired food is still good without eating

Tags: food, snack-food, food-safety, lifespan

If you're like me, then buying a new box of cracker or a new bag of sealed chips is not your first option, even if it's expired. Instead, you may just eat it and risk getting sick. So I am looking for an easy way to determine if a foodstuff that is expired without risking getting food poisoning is still okay to eat. For the sake of it, I'm only asking about food that is unopened until the point of determining if you can still eat it.

Comment: Yeah, let's not put our lives in the hands of folk wisdom like *"if it smells good, it probably won't kill you".* This is advice you can't possibly be taken seriously... or dispensed responsibly. If you have a question about the food safety of a particular product, our cooking site can handle these questions more responsibly: **[Seasoned Advice > Food Safety](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety)**

Comment: D'aw. I can never get a verified question in, no matter how hard I try. There's always tomorrow.

Comment: DeltaEscher, Yeah I saw that. It must be frustrating. Have a look at this ([A Lifehacks Manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)) and the linked [Unmanifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/the-un-manifesto-commentary-about-the-lifehack-site-and-how-we-got-here) and see if that helps any. Good luck.

Comment: I have, though I seem to be cursed in question asking.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if food is spoiled is to use your sight and smell. The first thing you will notice about spoiled food would be the off smell. If you can't smell anything strange or unusual then check for foreign colours and objects on the food.

The second way to check is by your gut feeling. If you think the food is off then it probably is !

Comment: This involves instincts